# Fill table with empty rows after data is filled

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a table:

```
    <table class="woohoo unity-hs">           
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>House</th>
          <th>Event</th>
          <th>Unitz</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>  
      <tbody> 
        <tr ng-repeat="item in houseList">
          <td> {{item.hname}} </td>
          <td> {{item.event}} </td>
          <td> {{item.points}} </td>
          <td> {{item.date}} </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

How can I populate my table with 10 empty rows even if there are no data at all. Or if there is only one row of information I want then to display 1 row with information and 9 empty rows. Do i need to use Angular or php? I tried to insert php code:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){ echo '<tr class="projtitletr"><td colspan="4"></td></tr>'; } ?>
```

But how can I use if else statement with angular data and combine it if there is information for 1 row I still want to display empty rows.

JS part:

```
$scope.historyHouseInit = function(fkhouseid) {
  $scope.fkhouseid = fkhouseid;
  $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'House/house_list.php',
    data: {fkhouseid:$scope.fkhouseid}
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.houseList = response.data;
    console.log(response);
  });
};
```

Comment: You could insert 10 blank row at the begining of `houseList` collection, `ng-repeat` will take care of rendering them on view

Comment: @PankajParkar how can I add 10 blank rows into `houseList` collection? Please see edit I added my js part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.houseList = [
    { hname: 'First' },
    { hname: 'Second' }
  ];
  $scope.limit = 10;
  $scope.remains = function() {
    var stubs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.limit - $scope.houseList.length; i++)
      stubs.push(i);    
    return stubs;
  }
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  Minimum rows count: <input type='text' ng-model='limit' />
  <br>
  <br>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>House</th>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Unitz</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in houseList">
        <td>{{item.hname}}</td>
        <td>{{item.event}}</td>
        <td>{{item.points}}</td>
        <td>{{item.date}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="stub in remains()">
        <td ng-repeat='x in [0,1,2,3]'>&nbsp</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```